Definite integral in solution of 2nd order non homogeneous ODE
Problem
I need to solve this second order linear non homogeneous ODE:
\begin{align}
    0 &= \ddot{x}_{t} - \delta \dot{x}_{t} - \kappa x_{t} + i_t - y_t \nonumber
\end{align}
where $\delta$ and $\kappa$ are constants, and $x$, $i$, $y$ are variables that depend on time. The following initial conditions are given: $x_{t_1} = \dot{x}_{t_1} = 0$.
Expected result
The solution should be:
\begin{align}
    x_{t} = \int_t^{t_1} \frac{e^{- r_1 (u-t)}}{r_2} \left( 1 - e^{- r_2 (u-t)} \right) \left( y_u - i_u \right) du
\end{align}
Question
Can someone help me understand how to complete the derivation? I am confused about the presence of a definite integral in the solution. It has been suggested in the comments that this has to do with Duhamel's principle but I am confused on how to proceed.
My attempt
First I find the general solution of the homogeneous equation. Substituting $x_{t} = e^{r t}$, I obtain the characteristic equation:
\begin{align}
    0 &= r^2  - \delta r - \kappa \nonumber \\
    r_{1,2} &= \frac{\delta \pm \sqrt{\delta^2 + 4 \kappa}}{2} \nonumber
\end{align}
Since $\delta^2 + 4 \kappa > 0$, there are two real distinct roots, and the general solution is given by:
\begin{align}
    x_{t}^h &= c_1 x_{t,1} + c_2 x_{t,2} \\
    &= c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t} \nonumber
\end{align}
Then, I find the particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation. The Wronskian is given by:
\begin{align}
    w(x_{t,1}, x_{t,2}) &= 
    \begin{vmatrix}
        e^{r_1 t} & e^{r_2 t} \\ 
        r_1 e^{r_1 t} & r_2 e^{r_2 t} 
    \end{vmatrix} \nonumber  \\
    &= (r_2 - r_1) e^{(r_1 + r_2) t} \nonumber
\end{align}
Since the Wronskian is non zero, I can use the variation of parameters method. The particular solution is given by:
\begin{align}
    x_{t}^p &= - x_{t,1} \int \frac{x_{u,2} \left( i_u - y_u \right) }{w} du + x_{t,2} \int \frac{x_{u,1} \left( i_u - y_u \right) }{w} du \\
    &= e^{r_1 t} \int \frac{e^{r_2 u} \left( y_u - i_u \right) }{(r_2 - r_1) e^{(r_1 + r_2) u}} du + e^{r_2 t} \int \frac{e^{r_1 u} \left( i_u - y_u \right) }{(r_2 - r_1) e^{(r_1 + r_2) u}} du \nonumber  \\
    &= \int \frac{e^{- r_1 (u - t)} \left( y_u - i_u \right) }{r_2 - r_1} du + \int \frac{e^{- r_2 (u - t)} \left( i_u - y_u \right) }{r_2 - r_1} du \nonumber \\
    &= \int \frac{\left( e^{- r_1 (u - t)} - e^{- r_2 (u - t)} \right) \left( y_u - i_u \right) }{r_2 - r_1} du \nonumber 
\end{align}
Finally, the general solution is given by the sum of the general solution of the homogeneous equation and the particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation.
\begin{align}
    x_{t} &= c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t} + \int \frac{\left( e^{- r_1 (u - t)} - e^{- r_2 (u - t)} \right) \left( y_u - i_u \right) }{r_2 - r_1} du \nonumber
\end{align}
It follows that:
\begin{align}
    \dot{x}_{t} &= c_1 r_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 r_2 e^{r_2 t} + \frac{\left( e^{- r_1 (u - t)} - e^{- r_2 (u - t)} \right) \left( y_u - i_u \right) }{r_2 - r_1}
\end{align}

This is effectively Duhamel's principle applied to a constant coefficients ODE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle#:~:text=T%20to%20T%2BdT%3A-,Constant%2Dcoefficient%20linear%20ODE,then%20superposing%20using%20Duhamel's%20integral.

Could I ask you if you can kindly provide some guidelines on how to proceed or an example that solves a second order ODE?
